# Expression Engine: Create multiple publish form tabs when installing a module

Tags: expressionengine

Is it possible to create a module that outputs two tabs into the publish screen, or do I have two create another module to to create my second tab or just another tab.file.php file?

**CODE**

**FILE:** upd.my_module.php

```
class My_module_upd {
    var $version = '1.0';

    public function __construct(){
        $this->EE =& get_instance();
    }

    public function install(){
    $this->EE->load->dbforge();

    $data = array(
            'module_name' => 'My Module',
            'module_version' => $this->version,
            'has_cp_backend' => 'y',
            'has_publish_fields' => 'y'
    );

    $this->EE->db->insert('modules', $data);
    return true;
    }

    public function tabs(){
    $tabs['tab_1'] = array(
        'field_1'   => array(
                            'visible'       => TRUE,
                            'collapse'      => FALSE,
                            'htmlbuttons'   => TRUE,
                            'width'         => '100%'
                            ),

        'field_2'       => array(
                            'visible'       => TRUE,
                            'collapse'      => FALSE,
                            'htmlbuttons'   => TRUE,
                            'width'         => '100%'
                            )
            );

    $tabs['tab_2'] = array(
            'field_1'   => array(
                    'visible'       => TRUE,
                    'collapse'      => FALSE,
                    'htmlbuttons'   => TRUE,
                    'width'         => '100%'
                ),
            );

    return $tabs;   
    }
```

}

**FILE:** tab.my_module.php

```
class My_module_tab {
public function __construct(){
    $this->EE =& get_instance();
}

public function publish_tabs($channel_id, $entry_id = ''){
    $settings = array(
            'field_1' => array(
                    'field_id'              => 'field_1',
                    'field_label'           => 'Field 1',
                    'field_type'            => 'text',
                    'field_required'        => 'n',
                    'field_data'            => '',
                    'field_text_direction'  => 'ltr',
                    'field_maxl'            => 100,
                    'field_instructions'    => '',
            ),
            'field_2'   => array(
                    'field_id'              => 'field_2',
                    'field_label'           => 'Field 2',
                    'field_type'            => 'text',
                    'field_required'        => 'n',
                    'field_data'            => '',
                    'field_text_direction'  => 'ltr',
                    'field_maxl'            => 100,
                    'field_instructions'    => '',
            ),
    );

    return $settings;
    }
 }
```

In the My_module_upd->tabs() method it looks like to can declare multiple tabs in the array but the My_module_tab class seems geared to controlling just one tab. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: No, you can't create more than one tab during install. And I wish that when I started EE development someone wiser had told me never to create tabs. You're nearly always better off creating a fieldtype. Care to elaborate on what your plugin does?

Comment: Its one of these http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/index.html

Comment: Of course, you can always rearrange your publish page once your module is complete though, and split your fields into separate tabs. Just not automatically during install as far as I'm aware.

Comment: The channel is a list of Job vacancies and the tabs would be a list of applicants, and a list of address, but I was going to use my own db tables because I need to do multiple joins between address to applicants. How would you split the fields?

Comment: Is this not something you could achieve with [Matrix](http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix) and/or [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa)? Or do you need to create an add-on?

Comment: After another look at it I have decided not to use tabs for this section of the program, but it would still be nice to know if I can create multiple tabs or if it is only one tab per module

Comment: been playing with a module tab. allthough i actually only needed one tab. From the docs (see layout class docs), it seems you could make a setup where you for instance manage the layouts and tabs from the module control panel for instance. **Beware** i had issues if the add-on didn't add the tab during install.